# jquery add / remove class from .parent()

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

i know this is incredibly easy  but I have been writing and rewriting this function for an hour with no success:

On click I want to add "active" to the `<li>` of the clicked link and remove "active" from all the other `<li>`'s in the navbar.

HTML:

```
   <nav>
     <ul>
       <li><a href="http://0327ea8.netsolhost.com/#home" class="home">Home</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://0327ea8.netsolhost.com/blog/" class="blog">Blog</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://0327ea8.netsolhost.com/#catalog" class="catalog">Catalog</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://0327ea8.netsolhost.com/#authors" class="authors">Authors</a></li>
       <li><a href="http://0327ea8.netsolhost.com/#store" class="store">Store</a></li>
     </ul>
   </nav>
```

jQuery:

```
  // NAVBAR ADD ACTIVE
   $("nav ul li a").click(function(){
     $("nav ul li").removeClass('active');
     $(this).stop().animate();
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
   });
```

This is adding the classes just fine but I can't get it to remove.

I've also tried separating it into to separate functions with no luck.

I have the .stop().animate() in there because I have a .animate() on the hover state of the links.

thanks!

edit:

this is the jQuery for the hover and the reason I have .stop().animate()

```
   $("nav ul li a, aside ul li.categories a, div.posts div.foot a").hover(function(){
     $(this).animate({'backgroundColor' : '#edf5e9'}, 200);
   },function() {
     $(this).animate({'backgroundColor' : '#ccd4c8'}, 600);
   });
```

I'm not sure why the .stop().animate() is wrong. If I don't have .animate() the active class won't stick, if I do, the active class does.

I still can't get the class to remove though :-/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
```

Comment: If you amend that to `$(this).parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');` it'd cover both the add, and remove, parts. Just leaving the strange `stop().animate()` part...

Comment: i have tried with and without the .stop().animate() and doesn't work either way. With .stop().animate() The active will be added but the remove doesn't work and with only .stop() (or without it all together) the class isn't added nor is it removed

Comment: @thomas Why are you doing `stop().animate()` instead of just `.stop()`?

Answer (score 5):

Try something even simpler:

```
 $('li.active').removeClass('active');
```